# OpenSSL configuration for PHP on Apache not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, openssl, mahara

I need OpenSSL working on an Apache 2 Webserver with PHP in order to use a combination of Moodle and Mahara with SSO.

The Server is running Ubuntu 10.04.3 and I've enabled the SSL package as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html). I've also followed [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/certificates-and-security.html) steps for setting up the certificates. Manually creating them worked fine.

However, Mahara does not see OpenSSL as correctly configured:

> Could not generate a new SSL key. Are you sure that both openssl and the PHP module for openssl are installed on this machine?

This is from the Apache error.log after starting the server:

```
[Thu Aug 25 10:38:06 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Aug 25 10:38:06 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Aug 25 10:38:06 2011] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Aug 25 10:38:06 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Aug 25 10:38:06 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Aug 25 10:38:06 2011] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Thu Aug 25 10:38:06 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k configured -- resuming normal operations
```

And this is what I get when visiting Maharas networking page, which says it couldn't find OpenSSL:

```
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] [WAR] 6d (api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1324) openssl_csr_new(): dn: add_entry_by_NID 17 -> Mahara for example.com (failed), referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Call stack (most recent first):, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * log_message("openssl_csr_new(): dn: add_entry_by_NID 17 -> Maha...", 8, true, true, "/var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php", 1324) at /var/www/mahara/lib/errors.php:446, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * error(2, "openssl_csr_new(): dn: add_entry_by_NID 17 -> Maha...", "/var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php", 1324, array(size 11)) at Unknown:0, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * openssl_csr_new(array(size 7), resource(#22), array(size 1)) at /var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1324, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * OpenSslRepo->generate_keypair() at /var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1238, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * OpenSslRepo->get_keypair() at /var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1145, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * OpenSslRepo->__construct() at /var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1131, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * OpenSslRepo::singleton() at /var/www/mahara/admin/site/networking.php:56, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] , referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] [WAR] 6d (api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1328) Could not generate a new SSL key. Are you sure that both openssl and the PHP module for openssl are installed on this machine?, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Call stack (most recent first):, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * OpenSslRepo->generate_keypair() at /var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1238, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * OpenSslRepo->get_keypair() at /var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1145, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * OpenSslRepo->__construct() at /var/www/mahara/api/xmlrpc/lib.php:1131, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx]   * OpenSslRepo::singleton() at /var/www/mahara/admin/site/networking.php:56, referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
[Thu Aug 25 10:45:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] , referer: http://example.com/mahara/admin/
```

I don't quite get it. What exactly is wrong?

**Edit**: Just to clarify: The issue seems to be with PHP, the Apache seems fine: `Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k configured -- resuming normal operations`

Comment: Did you correctly set up Apache virtual host ? can you paste the apache config files for your website on wich you want to enable SSL ?